# How identify the source file as a hard link? Bash Script

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, hyperlink

I'm making a shell script that identifies hard links to a directory, but I need to know the source file.
example:

```
Ln origen1.txt destino1.txt

Ln origen1.txt destino2.txt

Ln origen1.txt destino2.txt
```

The output should be origen1.txt, because this is the source file for other hard links. This should be in bash. I need help, Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please improve your question by posting some [properly formatted](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) code you've applied to the problem. In addition, please post **relevant** error messages verbatim, and take the time to share the steps you've taken so far to research or resolve things on your own.

Comment: All paths to regular files are hardlinks.  Directories are only allowed one link in the file system.  If `/path/foo` and `/path/bar` are each links to the same file, there is NO difference between them, and the question is meaningless.

Comment: To clarify: when you run `ln origin1.txt dest.txt`, it makes `dest.txt` a link to the same file that `origin1.txt` is a link to.  It does not make `dest.txt` a link to `origin1.txt`, rather they are both now links to the same file.

Answer (score 3):

You can't.  If you have a file `file1`, and you create a hardlink to it using `ln`:

```
ln file1 file2
```

Then the two files are indistinguishable.  A "hard link" is really just the same thing as a normal file entry; it just happens to point to the same file as another entry.  You can remove either one and you're back to having a single "hard link" to the file.

Answer (score 1):

Like people have pointed out, hard links are all equivalent. However, you can use `find` to find all the hard links of a file:

```
find / -samefile destino2.txt
```

It won't say which link was the first one, but it will tell you all the possible candidates.